# Checking the condition of clicking on the checkbox

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop

I have 3 `checkboxes` on my `activity`. I need to check status of `checkbox`(clicked/unclecked), and do specific action based on this result.
My logic in this work like:

```
if(Check1.isCheked) {
    //some action
} else if(Check2.isCheked) {
    //some action
} else if (Check3.isCheked) {
    //some action
} else if ((Check1.isCheked) && (Check2.isCheked)) {
    //some action
} else if ((Check1.isCheked) && (Check3.isCheked)) {
    //some action
} // etc.
```

If there are some more rational approach of this, because i, for example, have 9 `checkboxes` and for their verification, I need 509 conditions?

A concrete example of this situation in my code(it's what i wrote):

```
if (some_variable  == 1) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, activity.class);
        intent.putExtra("1", mCheck1.isChecked());
        intent.putExtra("2", (mCheck1.isChecked()) && (mCheck2.isChecked()));
        //and other 507 variants
        startActivity(intent);
} else if (some_variable == 2) {
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, activity.class);
        intent.putExtra("3", mCheck1.isChecked());
        intent.putExtra("4", (mCheck1.isChecked()) && (mCheck2.isChecked()));
        //and other 507 variants
        startActivity(intent1);
}
```

In next `activity` a get this checked results:

```
Boolean check1 = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("1");
Boolean check2 = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("2");

Boolean check3 = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("3");
Boolean check4 = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("4");
```

And than i start `for` loop to check this results:

```
if(check1) {
//query the database
} else if (check2) {
//query the database
} else if...
```

Comment: are the conditions always checking for `isChecked` or will it differ at times?

Comment: Nope, only checking for `isCheked`@Aominè

Comment: you can definitely create a method to help reduce the `&&` conditions but I can't think of a way to avoid the `if`, `else if` etc..

Comment: are there similarities in the `if` block for each of the `if`, `else if`'s?

Comment: I can't think too)@Aominè So i wrtote all the 509 conditions, but does it really all go that way in such a situation..

Comment: The cycle looks absolutely the same, only in my case, I check all possible options 9 checkboxes @Aominè

Comment: if you show what "some action" does maybe we can see if that logic can be improved.

Comment: In condition `if`, i use `putExtra`, to take "true/false" of use `checkbox`. Than, in next `activity`, i use `getExtra`, to take this result, and depending on what result I received, I make an appropriate request to the `database`.@Aominè

Comment: Note that if you follow this logic, `((Check1.isCheked) && (Check2.isCheked))` will never be executed even if it's true.. because `(Check1.isCheked)` would be evaluated and executed first.

Comment: So you want to say, that if my condition is `((Check1.isChecked) && (Check2.isCheked) && (Check3.isChecked))` will be similar in essence with `((Check1.isCheked) && (Check2.isCheked))`?@Taslim

Comment: For example, what key will be selected in this situation? `putExtra("1", ((Check1.isChecked) && (Check2.isCheked) && (Check3.isChecked)))` or `putExtra("2", ((Check1.isCheked) && (Check2.isCheked)))`? "1" or "2"? Can this change anything for my purposes?@Taslim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If I got your requirement wrong, please edit your question to clarify what you do in each if statement by providing examples)**

If I get your latest comment right and all you do in each is statement is setting a `Boolean` value on your `Intent` via `putExtra`, you could maybe use a `bit mask` to represent which checkboxes are checked.

That is a bit for each checkbox:

```
000000000 if nothing is checked  
000000001 if only the 1st checkbox is checked 
001001000 if 4th and 7th checkbox is checked 
etc..
```

From these binary numbers, you can then get an int representation of each possible combination. ie:

```
int intRepresentation = 0;
if(checkbox1Checked) intRepresentation += 1;
if(checkbox2Checked) intRepresentation += 2;
if(checkbox3Checked) intRepresentation += 4;
if(checkbox4Checked) intRepresentation += 8;
if(checkbox5Checked) intRepresentation += 16;
if(checkbox6Checked) intRepresentation += 32;
if(checkbox7Checked) intRepresentation += 64;
if(checkbox8Checked) intRepresentation += 128;
if(checkbox9Checked) intRepresentation += 256;
```

You then only need to create a list integers representing all the combination for which you want to add true. Example, if you want to set the value to true for the following 3 combinations:

```
checkbox1 (0000001 = 1)
checkbox3 and checkbox 5 (000010100 = 20)
checkbox6 (000100000 = 64)
```

you make this list:

```
List<Integer> myList = Arrays.asList(1, 20, 64)
```

Then

```
int intRepresentation = // whatever value you get from your selected checkboxes

myIntent.putExtra("VALUE_NAME", myList.contains(intRepresentation))
```

**EDIT:**

So given your concrete example, I have an other idea to extract all the && conditions and have a graphical representation which is easy to read

you can describe all your combinations as string, where each character represent the sate of a checkbox, "o" checked, "x" not checked, "-" ignore. Here are examples:

```
"o--------", // check1 is checked (ignore others)
"oo-------", // check1 and check2 are checked (ignore others)
"o--o-x---"  // check1 and check4 are checked and check6 is unchecked (ignore others)
```

Then you make an array out of it

```
String[] patterns = new String[] {
    "o--------", 
    "oo-------", 
    "o--o-x---" ,
    // and 506 other ones
    };
```

Then get the state of your checkboxes, assume that 1, 4, and 5 are checked, your actual situation is `"oxxooxxxx"`

Then you can define a method to see if your actual string matches a pattern

```
private boolean match(String actualPattern, String patternToMatch) {
    boolean match = true;
    for(int i=0; i<patternToMatch.length(); i++) {
        if(patternToMatch.charAt(i) != '-'
        && patternToMatch.charAt(i) != actualPattern.charAt(i)) {
            match = false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Given the following situation `"oxxooxxxx"` it will match patterns[0] (        `"o--------"`) because checkbox1 is checked and patterns[2] (`"o--o-x---"`) because checkboxes 1 and 4 are checked and 6 is not

Finally  change your code this way:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, activity.class);

if (some_variable  == 1) {
    intent.putExtra("1", match(stringRepresentation, patterns[0]));
    intent.putExtra("2", match(stringRepresentation, patterns[1]));
    //and other 507 variants
} else if (some_variable == 2) {
    intent.putExtra("3", match(stringRepresentation, patterns[0]));
    intent.putExtra("4", match(stringRepresentation, patterns[1]));
    //and other 507 variants
}

startActivity(intent);
```

**Further simplification:**

If, as it appears the code inside your ifs is the same and only the name of the extras are different, you can further simplify the code by replacing all your ifs this way:

Make a Map listing the names of the extras for each possible values of some_variable. In the example you wrote above, it would look like this.

```
Map<Integer, String[]> extraNames = new HashMap<Integer, String[]>() {{
    put(1, new String[] {"1", "2"});
    put(2, new String[] {"3", "4"});
}};
```

Then all your ifs can be removed and you can replace them by writing:

```
intent.putExtra(extraNames[some_variable][0], match(stringRepresentation, patterns[0]));
intent.putExtra(extraNames[some_variable][1], match(stringRepresentation, patterns[1]));
//etc ..
```

And it that works, I guess we can even go one step further and write

```
for(int i=0; i<extraNames.keySet().size(); i++) {
    intent.putExtra(extraNames[some_variable][i], match(stringRepresentation, patterns[i]));
}
```

Comment: You surprised me@Bentaye, I honestly never encountered a `bitmask`, I updated the question to make it clear what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: And if i understand, anyway i must to add all 509 variants of my choose, And this is doesn't simplify my task. But i read higher, that statemant that i wrote, doesn't work. I need to choose delete all my work, and begin again or i can continue, just take you advice in mind for future@Bentaye

Comment: @SpikeJohnson I added an Edit with an other idea which could be useful for your concrete example. That is how I would do it because you can write your 509 combinations in a graphical kind of way and it is easy to visualize them and change them if needed.

Comment: Big thanks @Bentaye, it's very interesting way) and what about refactoring, i can provide you all info, that needed.

Comment: @SpikeJohnson I mean in your example the code inside the ifs is the same, only the names of the extras change. If t is the case and the 509 conditions are the same in both cases then you could dynamically generate the names of the extras and only write the code inside the if once.

Comment: Yes, in three `if` loops, similar only values of `putExtra`, the names of the `putExtra` keys are all different@Bentaye

Comment: @SpikeJohnsonI added a last edit, see if you can get this working for you, it would be  a massive simplification